# Questions about visa Travel to Canada?

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens

I have 2 questions. I am submitting my visa application for Canada in few days...

1.) in the case of travel history, how do i detail it? Do i just upload the stamps alone, or i upload the stamps with details on what and where i went to and what i went to do in those locations.

2.) In the area of what i am going to do in Canada, i selected Tourism. Can i also in the main application form, detail what i am going to do, like for instance I would also be meeting some Venture Capital Companies for my startup in person, can I also include this in the application form?

Comment: Are you applying online or by paper applications?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella online at https://www.cic.gc.ca

Comment: "I would also be meeting some Venture Capital Companies for my startup in person, can I also include this in the application form?" You should, and you should also be aware that this makes you a business visitor, so you should refer to https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/business.html